# c++ Visual studio c99 editor support

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-editor

I'm using the Visual Studio 2017 editor to write c++ code and the Intel c++ compiler to compile it. The Intel compiler supports the c99 standard so I'm able to compile things like

```
int num = get_some_value_at_runtime();
int my_array[num];
```

but unfortunately the ide underlines as error every non constant value used to define arrays so my code might potentially be full of annoying little red lines that obscure the real errors.

[image]

I know that Microsoft doesn't support the c99 standard but my question is: is it possible to make the editor aware of the c99 support?

Comment: Even if MSVC supported C99, VLA's aren't C++. So there's that.

Comment: [*The variable length array (VLA) notation is a C99 \[ISO/IEC 9899\] feature and a compiler specific-extension of C++*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522649)

Comment: Yes I know. Sorry but my question is slightly different, I'm not interested in the fight of c vs c++, I've just asked if it is possible to let the Visual studio code editor take errors and, in general, information from the current selected compiler, in this case the Intel c++ compiler that supports vla.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The compiler didn't do any compilation until you press compile

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : the visual studio editor will highlight syntactical errors without compiling. I think the person asking the question is referring specifically to syntax highlighting. Makes sense given the fact that the Intel compilers (ICC) can be a back end in VS.ICC supports VLAs. I think the OP would prefer to have VS to understand VLA syntax (thus not underlining it as an error) without actually supporting the language feature.